# How to leverage HttpClientFactory in older frameworks?

Tags: c#, httpclient, .net-framework-version, httpclientfactory, ihttpclientfactory

In .NET Framework 4.6, I cannot instantiate DefaultHttpClientFactory internal class to leverage port exhaustion and DNS change features of IHttpClientFactory.

I tried using the static instance of HttpClientFactory but there is no documentation on if it handles pooling of HttpMessageHandlers and their lifetimes.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the [Microsoft.Extensions.Http nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/). It's netstandard2.0 and thus .NET Framework 4.6.1 compatible.

You can than use it by any of the methods described in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-7.0).

The only caveat is that you would need to use the new DI system, but that is pretty straightforward.

```cs
var services = new ServiceCollection();

services.AddHttpClient<MyHttpClient>(
    httpClient =>
    {
        httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://myapi.com");
    });

var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

var myHttpClient = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyHttpClient>();
```